# how to run a process on startup without CMD or ENTRYPOINT in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Here's some example dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get install xvfb

CMD Xvfb :0 -ac # <-- I need this to run on start up, no as CMD

CMD node programThatNeedsXvfbRunning.js
```

I need `Xvfb :0 -ac` to be running inside the image by default, so that I can do `docker run my-container someCustomCmdThatRequiresXvfbrunning`

I know I could do `Xvfb :0 -ac & node myapp` but that seems stupid to have to do this every time.

Comment: You need to create an entrypoint script that will run `Xvfb :0 -ac` and will then launch the command it receives as a param, either the `CMD` in your docker file or the one you pass on the command line that overrides it.

Comment: @Zeitounator how do I access 'CMD' from the script?

Comment: You can look at examples on any dockerhub image using an entry point (mysql, php, postgres....). People usually use `exec "$@"` once they have done all they needed.

Comment: You might also consider whether a VM (with simulated display hardware) running an ordinary desktop Linux distribution (starting a display server on startup) better meets your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Try this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get install xvfb

ENTRYPOINT [ "Xvfb", ":0", "-ac" ]
```

Then run it as:

```
docker run <image> cmd1 cmd2
```

This should behave as if you ran:

```
Xvfb :0 -ac cmd1 cmd2
```

Is this what you want?